# Fancybox and IE 9 RC

Tags: fancybox, internet-explorer-9

I'm guessing how to solve a fancybox issue in IE9 RC release.

Fancyboxes aren't loaded in this new browser (and bubbletip tooltip too..).

I think, reading another question, that's something related to dynamic stylesheet assigning unsupported in IE 9. But how ? How this could affect fancybox working ?

thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem with IE9 final..
For me, it was resolved disabling the "DivX HiQ" and "DivX Plus Web Player HTML5" add-ons

/edit
http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/b7eb4dd9efe817cc